# How to resolve browser auto translate causing server/client mismatched content

Tags: next.js, internationalization, middleware

I am building a website (next14, storyblok, i18n) and I've run into a browser issue with the auto google translate feature (Georgian or English). Georgian is my default language in my app so if I choose English the server content wants to render in English but the client is stuck on Georgian. How can I resolve this?

*Errors - Prop `lang` did not match. `Server: "en" Client: "ka"`*

Next14 middleware (app router) is set up as shown in docs

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
 
let locales = ["ka", "en"]
 
function getLocale(request) { 
  return "ka"
}
 
export function middleware(request) {
  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
  const pathnameHasLocale = locales.some(
    (locale) => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`
  )
 
  if (pathnameHasLocale) return
 
  // Redirect if there is no locale
  const locale = getLocale(request)
  request.nextUrl.pathname = `/${locale}${pathname}`
  // e.g. incoming request is /products
  // The new URL is now /en-US/products
  return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl)
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip all internal paths (_next)
    '/((?!_next).*)',
    // Optional: only run on root (/) URL
    // '/'
  ],
}
```

Pages accept lang from the params

```
export default async function Home({params: {lang} }) {
```

full repo found at https://github.com/BryanMF87/bokeria

I've tried changing getLocale content but not sure what to change it to use "ka" as a default.

I also tried changing the root layout html lang="ka" to html lang={lang} so it uses the {lang} value from params. I was hoping this would allow the client to adjust to the user language preference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal answer in my mind but it is a decent work around. I added **translate="no"** to my html tag.

Now the browser's auto translate feature still fires, but isn't able to translate the content automatically, preventing mismatched content errors between server and client.